# How to stop empty submits from posting to database?

Tags: php, mysqli, isset

I'm new to PHP. I added in the isset command, and the form is working with the database but every time I bring up this page it automatically submits a blank record to my database. How can I make it so that it only runs through the PHP commands if an input is entered and a user hits submit?

```
<?php
$handle = isset($_POST['handle']);
$address = isset($_POST['address']);
$code = isset($_POST['code']);

$rrr=mysqli_connect("localhost","knock_knock","whosthere","1");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Connection to DB failed" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$handle2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($rrr, $handle);
$address2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($rrr, $address);
$code2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($rrr, $code);

if(empty($handle)){
echo "Handle can not be empty";
}

$sql="INSERT INTO players (Handle, Address, Code)
VALUES ('$handle2', '$address2', '$code2')";

 if (!mysqli_query($rrr,$sql)) {
die ('Error: ' . mysqli_error($rrr));
}
echo "Record added";

mysqli_close($rrr);
?>
```

Comment: Wrap your insert code in a condition which checks whether the form is submitted

Comment: every refresh is actually another request, thus another insertion. after insertion, redirect the user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$handle = isset($_POST['handle']);
$address = isset($_POST['address']);
$code = isset($_POST['code']);
```

the above code will store true in all the variables if the are set.it should be -

```
$handle = isset($_POST['handle']) ? $_POST['handle'] : false;
$address = isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : false;
$code = isset($_POST['code']) ? $_POST['code'] : false;
```

and all code that is supposed to be executed after the form submit should be placed in -

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //code to be executed
}
```

`submit` or whatever the field is for submit button. and then the checks should be added for `empty` values.

you have to stop the execution or redirect.

```
if(empty($handle)){
    header('location:page.php?msg=yourmessage');
    exit;
}
```

or

```
if(empty($handle)){
    echo "Handle can not be empty";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Ok now the page goes straight to echo Handle can not be empty. The input forms don't even appear anymore... It seems like I need to create a separate PHP file one for before the user submits and another after they submit?

Comment: @m1xolyd1an . it is not necessary to create a new page if you add the checks properly then.

Comment: Great now its nice, removed the down-vote and gave you an up-vote :)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky . actually i was not considering all the circumstances of the code. thanks for pointing out. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Not sure what happened. I'll have to look at it further. Now it doesn't post to the database after adding the code

Comment: you might have missed something.check it. :)

Comment: @sgt  thank you this worked, perfectly! Guess I had to sleep on it :)

Answer (score 0):

Put a simple if condition at the top

```
$handle =$_POST['handle'];
if(empty(isset($handle)) || $handle=='')
{
    echo "Handle can not be empty";
}
else
{
    //Your stuff
}
```

Comment: Wrong, see the comment on the answer above

Comment: See your answer's edit history before you made this comment and notice what you changed and then see what was wrong :). The update is also incorrect. See @sgt's answer